# How to update a product database by entity framework core 1.0 rc2

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core

In entity framework core 1.0 RC1 when I published a website, it generated a ef.cmd file, I can ran `ef database update` to update the product database. How can I do it in RC2 when there is no ef.cmd file.

Answer (score 1):

With RC2, you need to install the tooling via your project.json file, then issue `dotnet restore`. Here is a sample project.json which also brings in EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
        "buildOptions": {
          "emitEntryPoint": true
        },

    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
      },

      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
        "type": "build",
        "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
      },

      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    },

    "tools": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
        "imports": ["portable-net451+win8"],
        "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
      }
    },

    "frameworks": {
      "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": "portable-net451+win8"
      }
    }
}
```

The important parts here are:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
}
```

And

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "imports": ["portable-net451+win8"],
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
  }
},
```

These tell the `dotnet restore` command to download the tooling for entity framework. Now you'll be able to use the [.NET Core CLI Entity Framework functionality](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#usage).

This will let you do things like:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add myMigration
$ dotnet ef database update
```